# How to get the value from NoteProperty?

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

How to get the value from NoteProperty?

I'm using powershell to get some data from Office365

```
Get-Mailbox | select EmailAddresses, UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress
```

The EmailAddresses is a NoteProperty. The value is similar to below, which includes SIP, X500, ...

[image]

Is there a simple way in powershell to get SIP value? Or, I have to use C# code to parse the SIP value?

Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried? Lots of examples if you search for `get-mailbox` + sip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a way to test it right now, but one way to do that might be like this:

```
Get-Mailbox | select EmailAddresses, UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress, @{Name='SIPAddress';Expression={$PSItem.EmailAddresses -match "sip:"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this (untested)?

```
$m = Get-Mailbox | select EmailAddresses, UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress

#Get one mailbox
$t = $m[0]
$t.EmailAddresses | Where-Object { $_.PrefixString -eq "sip"} | ForEach-Object { $_.AddressString }
```

Comment: thanks. the other one is simpler, so I choose it. but thanks too.